# Using some 'temporary variables' in QGIS Geometry generator symbol layer type expression?

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, geometry-generator

Making use of the `Geometry generator` symbol layer type, I draw rectangles of dimensions `@nv_bg_w` (width) and `@nv_bg_h` (height) (project variables) to line features, either at coordinates `text_x, text_y` (attributes, if not `NULL`) or alternatively at the center of the line by the following expression:

```
geom_from_wkt(
    'POLYGON((' ||
    COALESCE("text_x", x(point_on_surface($geometry))) ||' '||  COALESCE("text_y", y(point_on_surface($geometry))) || ','||
    (to_real(COALESCE("text_x", x(point_on_surface($geometry)))+ @nv_bg_w )) ||' '||  COALESCE("text_y", y(point_on_surface($geometry))) || ','||
    (to_real(COALESCE("text_x", x(point_on_surface($geometry)))+ @nv_bg_w  )) ||' '||  (to_real(COALESCE("text_y", y(point_on_surface($geometry))))- @nv_bg_h ) || ','||
    COALESCE("text_x", x(point_on_surface($geometry))) ||' '||  (to_real(COALESCE("text_y", y(point_on_surface($geometry))))- @nv_bg_h ) || ','||
    COALESCE("text_x", x(point_on_surface($geometry))) ||' '||  COALESCE("text_y", y(point_on_surface($geometry)))|| '))'
)
```

As can be seen `x(point_on_surface($geometry))` and `y(point_on_surface($geometry))` occur very often. At least in this simple example, this makes the code harder to read than it would have to.

So my question is: Is there a way to store the latter expressions in some temporary variables, something like (pseudocode):

```
@mx=x(point_on_surface($geometry))
@my=y(point_on_surface($geometry))
geom_from_wkt(
'POLYGON((' ||
... #and so on
```

Comment: Jochen, did you find any solution to the problem described in your question? I'm facing a similar need and am searching for the same thing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a way in QGIS 3.x. You can set a variable by means of `with_variable()` function within an expression. So I expect the expression below will work for you.

```
with_variable( 'mx', x(point_on_surface($geometry)),
    with_variable( 'my', y(point_on_surface($geometry)),
        geom_from_wkt(
            'POLYGON((' ||
            COALESCE("text_x", @mx) ||' '||  COALESCE("text_y", @my) || ','||
            (to_real(COALESCE("text_x", @mx)+ @nv_bg_w )) ||' '||  COALESCE("text_y", @my) || ','||
            (to_real(COALESCE("text_x", @mx)+ @nv_bg_w  )) ||' '||  (to_real(COALESCE("text_y", @my))- @nv_bg_h ) || ','||
            COALESCE("text_x", @mx) ||' '||  (to_real(COALESCE("text_y", @my))- @nv_bg_h ) || ','||
            COALESCE("text_x", @mx) ||' '||  COALESCE("text_y", @my)|| '))'
        )
    )
)
```

Documentation in expression dialog window:

[image]